# Advanced List Comprehension: how can I fit multiple for loops in one list comprehension?

Tags: python

I have been trying to fit the following list of words from a text file into one list comprehension:

`file = open("Lincoln.txt", "r").read().split()`

```
world_list = []                                            

for v in file:
    word_list.append(v.translate(str.maketrans("", "",string.punctuation)).lower())
    for i in word_list:
         if i != '':
            world_list.append(i)
```

This is succesful, but I'm not sure how to include the second part of the for loop in that same list comprehension:

`word_list = [v.translate(str.maketrans("", "",string.punctuation)).lower() for i,v in enumerate(word_list)]`

Without the second part, I still get empty strings from my word extraction:

[click to see my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4hJp.png)

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edited

```
[i for i in (v.translate(str.maketrans("", "",string.punctuation)).lower() for v in word_list) if i != '']
```

Comment: Edited the answer. A little in the blind spot here. Give it a try.